# Gnome Activities Search does not search in files contents

Tags: linux, ubuntu, search, gnome3, ubuntu-18.04

I added several other folders using the `gnome-control-center` (and since I am using Ubuntu 18.04, I did `sudo apt install tracker` before to enable this option). I can search for the files, but only using filenames, not using it's content. This was different on Ubutnu 17.10, and I want this functionality back. On Askubuntu, no one was able to help me.

I discovered that, when I watch the trackers daemons, it skips the property `nie:plainTextContent`:

```
~> tracker daemon -w
Ressourcen-Aktualisierungen der Datenbank werden nun überwacht
Alle Eigenschafte »nie:plainTextContent« werden ausgelassen

Drücken Sie Strg+C zum Anhalten
```

(german output, sorry)

It seems like this is exactly the property I need:

```
~> tracker extract ~/watched_folder/file.pdf 
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix nie: <http://www.semanticdesktop.org/ontologies/2007/01/19/nie#> .
@prefix nfo: <http://www.semanticdesktop.org/ontologies/2007/03/22/nfo#> .

<file:///home/user/watched_folder/file.pdf> nfo:pageCount 51 ;
  nie:title "Lecture_File" ;
  a nfo:PaginatedTextDocument ;
  nie:plainTextContent "long text from the pdf" # this is what I want to search in!
```

Do you have any idea how I can enable content based search, or especially how I can enable this property? Why is it disabled?